# Inserting special character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, currency

I have a table that contains these columns:

```
Country  Varchar(50)
Currency Nvarchar(10)
```

I want to insert currency (rubble) for country Russia. I inserted currency for India using `NCHAR(8377)`. But I'm not able to insert currency for Russia.

```
insert into Currency (country, currency)
values ('Indian Rupee', NCHAR(8377) );

Country      Currency
India         ₹
Russia
```

Comment: Could you share your insert statement?

Comment: Why did you show us the code that *did* work, and not the code that **doesn't**?

Comment: Looks like 8381 is the Decimal for the Unicode Russian Ruble [from here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20bd/index.htm) You could probably just toss in the actual character for it too: `₽`. Assuming that your client and connection to your server is Unicode. If you are on Windows you can pop open Character Map and dig it out of there for copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NCHAR(8381)

```
insert into Currency (country, currency)
values ('russian ruble', NCHAR(8381) );
```

[image]

Reference : http://www.xe.com/symbols.php

Comment: Sorry i was not aware about the comment by JNebill. :(

Comment: I used below insert statement in sql server.After insertion in is showing like (₽)that in that table. Insert into Currency (country, currency)
values ('russian ruble', NCHAR(8381));

Comment: exact rubble symbol is not displaying in the table.it is display  like ₽.is it possible to display exact rubble symbol in the table?.Ex:For Indian currency it is displaying correctly in the table ₹.

Comment: @Ram I tried it from my side and it is adding properly. I have added the result in my answer. Please check.